# How i can add flutter module to android app with AndroidStudio BumbleBee

Tags: android-studio, flutter-module

I can't find "Flutter Module" in Modules
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is not currently supported:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5914

This is an android studio issue so adding a module manually in the appropriate config files should still work. If you could give more details on what specifically you're trying to do maybe there is an easier work around.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have encountered this problem too. Anyway, we still can make it manually. Check this doc to make it.
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup